# EWS C# error: does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to write a program to read through an exchange mailbox. I'm very new to c#, so please excuse if the error is too obvious.

Here's the code and it fails when I try to bind the EmailMessage and gives me the error - "**The name 'id' does no exist in the current context**"

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ResetOraclePassword
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("abc@xyz.com", "xxxxxxx");
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
            service.AutodiscoverUrl("abc@xyz.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
            Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
            PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageHeaders, EmailMessageSchema.Body, EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments,
            EmailMessageSchema.Subject, EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.Sender, EmailMessageSchema.DisplayCc, EmailMessageSchema.DisplayTo, EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived, 
            EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId);
            propSet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;

            EmailMessage abc = EmailMessage.Bind(service, id, propSet);
            Console.WriteLine(abc.Subject);
            Console.WriteLine(abc.InternetMessageId);
            Console.WriteLine(abc.DateTimeReceived.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(abc.From.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(abc.DisplayTo);
            Console.WriteLine(abc.DisplayCc);
            Console.WriteLine(abc.Body.Text);
         }
        private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            bool result = false;
            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the error message do you not understand? You never define `id` anywhere.

Comment: although the method is asking for a parameter that is called `id` it is still your job to provide a valid input. So you need to take care of the proper initialization of the variables beforehand

Answer (score 3):

the error should be in this line

```
EmailMessage abc = EmailMessage.Bind(service, id, propSet);
```

it said that `id`is not defined in your code, so you need to initialize `id` in your code. For example, if `id` is string then you can define like

```
string id = "any value";
```